# How to set a date/time in front-end access that is compatible with back-end SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, ms-access

We use Access 2016 as a front end and SQL Server 2008 as back end.

A user creates a new record in a form. In order to generate an autonumbered ID for this new record, I use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`. When I use this command, the form moves off of that record. I need to then find the ID of the record just created. I cannot search for the largest autonumber ID because we use merge replication and different users have different ID ranges.

I tried making a `DateCreated` column and defaulting that column to the current date and time by using `GetDate()` in SQL Server, but that that makes Access give lock errors and other errors because it cannot properly read SQL Server's datetime format.

Is there a `.saverecord` option that doesn't move off the current record in a form? Or is there a date/time field that won't produce an error when using SQL Server backend and Access frontend?

In a nutshell, I need the autonumbered ID of the last record created in a form.

Comment: That command should not move the form off of the record. You better to use if me.Dirty = True then me.Dirty = false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run another command in the same session to get the id:
`SELECT @@IDENTITY`

For more details check the: [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815629) documentation.

Anyway, if you have an API to access the database, and it doesn't expose this, it should be expended to return the scope identity, since this is the only reliable way to know what ID was generated.

Comment: I coding in the VBA front end, not running procedures on the SQL data.  Is there an equivalent of this in VBA code?

Comment: You just need to run another query in the same session to fetch @@IDENTITY - check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815629)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pass through query to run this SQL statement after you insert your record:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID
```

It will return the last created identity used in the current scope.

Comment: There is for getting the latest identity for a local Access table, but you'll have to call this to get it from SQL Server using a pass through recordset in VBA

Comment: Ahhh I've never done this before...called a SQL Server from VBA.  I suppose the time has come to leave my cozy VBA shell.  It appears I need to open the connection to SQL and then query the table.   Will attempt this, thank you!

Comment: No, you don't have to leave the VBA part unless some one who knows zero about access try to make a suggestion about Access without zero knowledge. When the form saves the record, then the auto number ID is available in the forms record set and the value can be referenced like any other column in that form (me!ID). The only confusing part here is why the form is moving off the record when you save the record – it should not. Such tables should also have a timestamp column (sql rowversion). As to how the select command will be executed in a bound form begs this question - it not required.

Answer (score 0):

To get the auto number field to populate in an Access form bound to a sql server table you simply need to force the form to save the record. The act of saving the record does not and should not and will not move the form off of the record.

The code to get the auto number is thus:

```
If me.Dirty = True then  Me.Dirty = false
Debug.print "Auto number from SQL server = " & me!id
```

You as a general rule cannot use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() since the connection used in the form will be different then the connection you use to execute the SQL pass-through query. So the responses here are wild goose chase and incorrect and the wrong way to approach this problem.